# Authorize.net - bulk upload via cim

Tags: php, csv, authorize.net

I am successfully using Authorize.net CIM via PHP to charge and then recharge credit cards using their xml api.

The information which I need when I want to recharge their card is 
their customerProfileId which I use to get their customerPaymentProfileId
and then am able to charge up to the amount which has previously been authorized.

1. Is the customerPaymentProfileId static? As in, do I only need to retrieve it once and then it won't change 'ever' change?
2. Am I able to use the bulk upload feature of authorize.net as described at:
   http://www.authorize.net/files/uploadguide.pdf
   And if so, where should I be putting those fields?
3. If I am unable to use the bulk upload feature, would a solution be to just loop through the transactions that I have under my current PHP script, or may there be complications that would be introduced by doing that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is the customerPaymentProfileId static? As in, do I only need to retrieve it once and then it won't change 'ever' change?

Yes, it is static and will never change. If it wasn't this service would never work.

> Am I able to use the bulk upload feature of authorize.net as described at: http://www.authorize.net/files/uploadguide.pdf And if so, where should I be putting those fields?

No.

> If I am unable to use the bulk upload feature, would a solution be to just loop through the transactions that I have under my current PHP script, or may there be complications that would be introduced by doing that.

That would be exactly what you want to do. CIM is typically paired with a home-grown automated billing system. Usually to handle recurring billing with varying payment amounts. Those systems will do this very thing.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.
The reason why I wasn't sure if it was static, is because customerProfileId is static and can be used to retrieve it. Just seems slightly surprising that you would need both of these.